# Svelte Components as Object Properties

Tags: typescript, svelte, typescript-generics

I want to accept a component as a prop.

```js
import AComponent from './AComponent.svelte';

type MyType = {
  [key: string]: any; // just an example
}

type IWantToAcceptAComponent<T> = {
  component: SvelteComponentTyped<{ record: T }>;
}

const componentPropObject: IWantToAcceptAComponent<MyType> = {
  component: AComponent // error here
}
```

```
Error: Type 'typeof AComponent__SvelteComponent_' is missing the following properties from type 
'SvelteComponentTyped<{ record: MyType; }>': $set, $on, $destroy, $$prop_def, and 5 
more.ts(2740)
```

I figured it might be that the typedef should be:

```js
type IWantToAcceptAComponent<T> = {
  component: typeof SvelteComponentTyped<{ record: T }>;
}
```

But that causes even weirder errors.

It's fairly important that this typing is explicit, as it's supposed to be part of an exported interface for users.

Comment: as far as i know it's not a good idea to pass component as a props

Comment: why do you want to pass a component as a props

Comment: Mainly because the component is extremely data-based, and the only way I can keep all of the related types, well, related, is to manage that relationship through the types of the props I pass around. Additionally, it's a fallacy to say that it's a bad idea to pass a component as props (or at least part of an object)... it's literally in the Svelte quickstart! https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-component

Answer (score 5):

You need to adjust your typing of `IWantToAcceptAComponent`. You can't use `SvelteComponentTyped` directly because that means you want the instance type, not the constructor type. But you also can't do `typeof SvelteComponentType<..some generic>` because that's a syntax error for TypeScript. You need to type the "accepts a class constructor that returns a specific instance" using Svelte's provided `ComponentType` interface like this:

```
import type { ComponentType, SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte';

type IWantToAcceptAComponent<T> = {
  component: ComponentType<SvelteComponentTyped<{ record: T }>>;
  // If you're on and old Svelte version which doesn't provide ComponentType yet:
  componentAlternative: new (...args: any) => SvelteComponentTyped<{ record: T }>;
}
```

Note that you need Svelte for VS Code version 105 or greater and (if you use it) `svelte-check` 2.0.0 or greater for this to work. There was a slight mismatch of the typings previously.

If you want to use the code inside a TypeScript file, you need to activate the TypeScript plugin of the Svelte for VS Code extension. Else all Svelte imports are typed as a generic `SvelteComponentDev` without the proper types.

Comment: You're a lifesaver -- I thought I'd replied to this earlier! Thanks so much for the help. That took care of it!

Comment: Gah, I spoke too soon -- it looked like it was working, but it's not. I'm now getting this error:

Type 'typeof SvelteComponentDev' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: any) => SvelteComponentTyped<{ record: Row<AmenityRuleRow>; }, any, any>'.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you want to use the code inside a TS file. I updated my answer accordingly. In general, TS/Svelte file interop is tricky and not quite matching up sometimes and you need the TS plugin to get better interop.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't use typescript, I see no reasons why this would be possible with pure JS but not with TS.
I've made [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9c92bbfcd7ab4bf598c85fae22603b01?version=3.38.2) which basically wraps two other 'sub components' passed as props.

The structure is something like :

App.svelte

```
<script>
  //App.svelte
  import A from "./A.svelte";
  import B from "./B.svelte";
  import Wrapper from "./Wrapper.svelte";

  let props = [  { component: A }, { component: B } ];
</script>

<Wrapper {props} />
```

Wrapper.svelte :

```
<script>
    //Wrapper.svelte
    export let props = [];
</script>

{#each props as prop}
    <p>
        <svelte:component this={prop.component} />
    </p>
{/each}
```

A.svelte :

```
   <!-- A.svelte -->
   <h2>COMP A</h2>
```

B.svelte :

```
    <!-- B.svelte -->    
    <h3>COMP B</h3>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right -- it's possible! The question is about what typings are necessary to make it strongly typed. If I just change the type definition to component: any, everything's fine and good. But I'd prefer strong typing.